# c++11 GCC compiling failing

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11

Trying to compile code containing c++11  and  with g++(provided by Mingw) on windows 7 x64. The part that fails is.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
mutex locka;
thread *threads_a = new thread[20];
```

Compiling with -std=c++11 and -pthreads. Getting errors:

- 'mutex' does not name a type
- 'thread' does not name a type

Any suggestions how to compile this? I need to use C++11  so i can't look at alternatives.

Comment: I think mingw is missing threading stuff still

Comment: Which version of Mingw?

Comment: Version 4.8.1 if understood the question.

Comment: Got it to work, too bad that it is 4 am and i no longer remember which of those things i downloaded. Now i only need to figure out how to not use Thread_local or to code it in way that it isn't needed.